# Pegar Penúltimo registro de uma tabela com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Como eu faço para pegar o penúltimo registro de uma tabela com Entity Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var penultimoRegistro = db.Entidade.OrderByDescending(/*ordenação*/).Take(2).Last();
```

O que esse código faz é pegar os dois últimos registros conforme a ordenação especificada e salvar na variável o último registro desses dois (já que a ordenação é `Descending`).

**Edit:**

Você também pode fazer

```
db.Entidade.OrderByDescending(/*ordenação*/).Take(2).Skip(1).Take(1).Single();
```

Esse código pega os dois últimos registros conforme sua ordenação, e pula um registro o `Single()` serve para fazer o retorno ser um `T` ao invés de `IEnumerable<T>`.

No fim, o resultado final é o mesmo.

[Veja um exemplo no dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R9OSR8)

Comment: Pode usar o Skip pra não precisar retornar 2 e selecionar o último. Só trocar `Take(2).Last();` por `Skip(1).Take(1).Single();`

Comment: Também pode ser, vou adicionar essa opção.